# Python type annotation for slice?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have this generic function:

```
def slice(seq):
    return seq[1:3]

assert slice("abcde") == "bc"
assert slice(b"xyz") == b"yz"
assert slice([2,7,1,8]) == [7,1]
```

We can see that `slice` has types `str -> str`, `bytes -> bytes`, `List[int] -> List[int]`.

How do I write the type annotation for the function? Here is a wrong attempt ([`TypeVar` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)):

```
from typing import *

E = TypeVar("E")
T = TypeVar("T", bytes, str, Sequence[E])

def slice(seq: T) -> T:
    return seq[1:3]
```

It produces these error messages:

```
error: Type variable "mymodule.E" is unbound
note: (Hint: Use "Generic[E]" or "Protocol[E]" base class to bind "E" inside a class
note: (Hint: Use "E" in function signature to bind "E" inside a function)
```

I'm running Python 3.9.6 and mypy 0.910.

Comment: Given that both `bytes` and `str` are already [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), would `T = TypeVar('T', Sequence)` not suffice?

Comment: I'd bookmark [this very helpful page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). It outlines what ABCs are associated with each type of functionality/methods.

Comment: @Brian "TypeError: A single constraint is not allowed".

Comment: @Nayuki They mean `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Sequence)` I believe.

Comment: @PeterWood `Sequence`s should definitely be subscriptable. To be a `Sequence`, it must implement `__getitem__`. It's `Collection`s that aren't subscriptable.

Comment: Odd, OP's code doesn't give me any warnings or errors

Comment: @Carcigenicate apologies, I was getting confused with my terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a `TypeVar` with a `bound` of `Sequence`.

```
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar, cast

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=Sequence)


def slice(seq: _T) -> _T:
    return cast(_T, seq[1:3])


assert slice("abcde") == "bc"
assert slice(b"xyz") == b"yz"
assert slice([2, 7, 1, 8]) == [7, 1]
```

Note the `cast` inside `slice` is necessary because the slice operator isn't actually guaranteed (at least as of Python 3.8 according to the `Sequence` abstract class) to return the same type as the original object.

You can get around this and have stronger typing by defining your own `Slicable` protocol (for which you need to stop shadowing the builtin `slice` type):

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

_S = TypeVar('_S', bound='Slicable')


class Slicable(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self: _S, i: slice) -> _S: ...


_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=Slicable)


def my_slice(seq: _T) -> _T:
    return seq[1:3]


assert my_slice("abcde") == "bc"
assert my_slice(b"xyz") == b"yz"
assert my_slice([2, 7, 1, 8]) == [7, 1]
```

With this typing no casting is needed, and `my_slice` will only permit arguments whose types implement slicing operations that return the same type of object.  For example, if I define a class whose `__getitem__` returns an arbitrary string:

```
class TrickySlicable:
    def __getitem__(self, i: slice) -> str:
        return "foo"

my_slice(TrickySlicable())  # error: Value of type variable "_T" of "my_slice" cannot be "TrickySlicable"
```

Similar failures are produced for dict arguments (which implement `__getitem__` but not with a slice as the index) and types that don't implement `__getitem__` at all.

Comment: I tested your code and it seems good. It would be nice to avoid casting, because that's a code smell. Without the cast, I get the error message "Incompatible return value type (got "Sequence[Any]", expected "T")". This suggests that `Sequence` has an inner type but gets lost because your bound is `Sequence`, not `Sequence[E]` (which I don't know how to express).

Comment: @Nayuki see updated answer for an alternate implementation using `Protocol` which is a little more complex but eliminates the `cast`.  I believe if `Sequence` were implemented as a similar protocol it'd make the easier version work without the cast -- probably in a future Python version!

Comment: Yup, the second half of your response was even better and I incorporated that into my codebase cleanly. It will show up in https://www.nayuki.io/res/cryptographic-primitives-in-plain-python/cryptocommon.py in a few days.