# How to annotate slice type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, python-typing

I want to use `slice[int]` like `list[int]`, but my IDE tells me that this usage is invalid. So how to annotate slice type, if I want to constrain the type of its parameters?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Comment: You can use something like this - `def func(var1: List[int], var2: slice)`: `return var1[s]`

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876078/python-type-annotation-for-slice. I guess you could also use Tuple[int]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update (2023-05-12)

I opened a [PR to make `slice` generic](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/10174). The change would introduce quite a few `mypy` errors in many existing projects. The good people at `python/typeshed` made it clear that until we have **type variable defaults** (proposed in [PEP 696](https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/#using-another-typevarlike-as-default), but not yet accepted) and the `slice` type utilizes them, they will not accept the change to make it generic.

I will try to keep up to date on the progress with PEP 696 and to implement the missing changes as soon as possible.

---

### Original answer

As it stands right now, the built-in `slice` type is **not generic**, so it has no type parameters (unlike e.g. `list`). There has been a long-standing [discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/159) about this (since 2015) and the relevant [`typeshed` issue](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/8647) is still open. IMO it should *definitely* be made generic, but it is unclear if/when that will happen.

`slice` arguments can be of *any* type ([source](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi)). This means a statement like e.g. `slice("foo", [-1], object())` will pass `mypy --strict` (even though it may be of questionable utility).

That means there is currently no way to constrain a slice type variable in terms of its start/stop/step attribute types.

And since you cannot even subclass `slice`, there is not even a way to easily make your own generic slice-like type.

Comment: There is such a way: `it TYPE_CHECKING: class MySlice(Generic[_T]): ...; else: MySlice = slice` (the last line may need a `type: ignore` comment). This way you can make your own slice typing easily.

Comment: @SUTerliakov True, but that does not really help in any practical context. Whenever you actually need to _use_ a slice object, e.g. for slicing a `list`, the type checker will not accept `MySlice` unless it inherits from `builtins.slice`. You would need to convert/cast your custom `MySlice` into a normal `slice` or place `# type: ignore` directives everywhere.

Comment: Ah, you're right. However, something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=77b5d146011b991b9a04b065d337b2c6) (inheriting from slice in `if TYPE_CHECKING` with ignore comment for final class - anyway this code is never executed) works.